# validate form only if any radio button is select

Tags: angularjs

I want to enable my form's Ok button only if any of the checkbox is checked, but not sure why its not working. Here is my code

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <li ng-repeat="i in templates">
        <input name="myTemplate" ng-model="myTemplate" type="radio" ng-value="{{i.id}}"  />
        <span>{{i.name}}</span>
    </li>
    <button ng-disabled="!templates.length || !myTemplate" ng-class="{'disabled' : !templates.length || !myTemplate}" class="btn btn-primary ok-btn">
        Submit
    </button>   
</form>
```

Submit button is always disabled whether I check any radio button or not

Comment: Probably a dot rule issue. I let you google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `Object` instead of just value in `ng-model`.

JS:

```
  $scope.myTemplate = {};;

  $scope.templates = [
    {id: 1, name: 'One'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Two'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Three'}
  ];
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <li ng-repeat="i in templates">
        <input name="myTemplate" ng-model="myTemplate.value" type="radio" ng-value="{{i.id}}"  />
        <span>{{i.name}}</span>
    </li>
    <button ng-disabled="!templates.length || !myTemplate.value" ng-class="{'disabled' : !templates.length || !myTemplate}" class="btn btn-primary ok-btn">
        Submit
    </button>   
</form>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/eKH2AaPIOEcplfxOsMHQ?p=preview